# A way to call a subscription for each value within the subscription value without callback hell

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables, rxjs-observables

So I currently have a subscription which returns teams and inside of teams theres an array which stores users Object. I would like to call another subscription for each of these users.
Heres a view of the team object:

```
team: {
    teamName: 'blueberries',
    teamMembers: [{UserObject}, {UserObject}]
}
```

Heres a look at the userObject:

```
user: {
    uid: 1,
    uname: 'DPR'
}
```

I currently have this code where I subscribe to a getRequest for the team and then tap the team Observable and get the users array and then for each I run a subscription. Heres the code:

```
this.teamService.getTeam(id)
   .pipe(
       tap(team => {
          team.teamMembers.forEach((eachUser) => {this.userService.updateUser(eachUser).subscribe()})
       })
   )
   .subscribe()
```

Although it works, I would really like to avoid a subscription within a subscription I have tried doing it with `switchMap` but it doesnt seem to run the code within the `switchMap` operator. Heres the code I tried but didn't work:

```
this.teamService.getTeam(id)
   .pipe(
       tap(team => {
          team.teamMembers.forEach((eachUser) => 
          switchMap(() => {return this.userService.update(eachUser)})
       })
   )
   .subscribe()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following

```js
    this.teamService
      .getTeam(id)
      .pipe(switchMap((team) => this.updateMembers(team)))
      .subscribe();
```

```js
  private updateMembers(team: Team) {
    return forkJoin(
      team.teamMembers.map((member) => this.userService.update(eachUser))
    );
  }
```

The reason your code doesn't work is because you're never subscribing to userService.update().

Answer (score 1):

You can map your array of `team` into an array of `userService.updateUser` calls.
Then you can subscribe to those calls with `forkJoin(calls)`, `merge(...calls)`, or `concat(...calls)`.

They each have different behaviour depending on how you want your calls subscribed and how you want to receive the results. Since you're not getting results from `updateUser`, `merge` or `forkJoin` is probably fine.

That looks like this:

```js
this.teamService.getTeam(id).pipe(
  map(team => team.teamMembers.map(user => 
    this.userService.updateUser(user)
  )),
  switchMap(serviceCalls => merge(...serviceCalls))
).subscribe();
```

You can combine `map` and `switchMap` like this:

```js
this.teamService.getTeam(id).pipe(
  switchMap(team => merge(...
    team.teamMembers.map(user => 
      this.userService.updateUser(user)
    )
  ))
).subscribe();
```